# Adding sub-menu to vertical menu CSS

Tags: css

This should be vertical menu with 2nd level sub menu as you can see 2 2.1 2.2 
I tried many tutorials but just couldn't make it work i know lot of code for sub-menu is missing but honestly i have no idea what to do with it to fix it .

```css
.menu ul li a {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  font-family: comic sans ms;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 25px;
  width: 160px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em;
  border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em;
  border-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: url(link.cur), auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 9px 11px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: block;
}
.menu ul li a:visited {
  color: white;
}
.menu ul li a:hover,
.menu_simple ul li .current {
  color: white;
  background-color: #0099CC;
  /* green #5FD367 */
}
.menu ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul {
  left: 150px;
  top: 0px;
  display: block;
}
.menu ul li ul li a {
  color: #454444;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">2.1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">2.2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="#">3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.. why did you use absolute to `.menu ul li ul` this code was causing problem !!

```css
.menu ul li a {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  font-family: comic sans ms;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 25px;
  width: 160px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em;
  border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em;
  border-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: url(link.cur), auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 9px 11px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: block;
}
.menu ul li a:visited {
  color: white;
}
.menu ul li a:hover,
.menu_simple ul li .current {
  color: white;
  background-color: #0099CC;
  /* green #5FD367 */
}
.menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul {
  left: 150px;
  top: 0px;
  display: block;
}
.menu ul li ul li a {
  color: #454444;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">2.1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">2.2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="#">3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```